# Spring MBean client thinks MBean service is RMI connection

Tags: java, spring, rmi, jmx, mbeans

I'm having problems connecting my own Spring MBean client to the "Hello World!" service as seen in the [JMX examples from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jmx/examples.html).  The service and included client are working fine.

I think it has to do with an RMI connection coming back when it's expecting something else... but I don't know what the solution would be, or even if that is a correct inference.

Or am I somehow using the "wrong" MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean ?

Any ideas?

Here's my spring config for this bean:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="mBeanServerClient"
      class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl"
              value="service:jmx:rmi://localhost/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmxClient"
      class="com.foo.jmx.MBeanPollingClient">
    <property name="mbeanServerConnection"
              ref="mBeanServerClient" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Here's my implementing code:

```
import org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean;

public class MBeanPollingClient {

    private MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean mbeanServerConnection = null;

    public void setMbeanServerConnection ( MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean m )
    {
        mbeanServerConnection = m;
    }

    public MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean getMbeanServerConnection ( )
    {
        return mbeanServerConnection;
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jmxClient' defined in class path
>   resource [jmx-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type
>   'javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection'
>   to required type
>   'org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean' for
>   property 'mbeanServerConnection'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection]
>   to required type
>   [org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean] for
>   property 'mbeanServerConnection': no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found

Comment: Your question is back to front. What you looked up *is* a JMX service bean connection. The exception says so. The real question is why did you think it would be something else?

Comment: The code I'm using is copied directly from the Spring examples - I thought it could connect to the JMX Service Bean, because that seems like the entire premise of the Spring connector.

I'm not expecting the property to be a RMI connection, but the exception seems to think it is - that is the thing that comes back is apparently a RMI connection.  Am I reading the exception wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will give you an `MBeanServerConnection` provided by the factory. To fix the error just change

```
private MBeanServerConnectionFactoryBean mbeanServerConnection;
```

to

```
private MBeanServerConnection mbeanServerConnection;
```

Comment: Do you know why ? Is there a documentation explaining the reason somewhere ?